# Simple calculus question re: the Work-Energy theorem (change of variables)

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I have the following proof for the Work-Energy theorem (with the usual notation).

[image: Picture of proof]

Where I'm getting lost is basically at the line break, clearly just missing something very obvious. How is it that we can say that

$$
m \int^{x_2}_{x_1} \frac{dv}{dt} dx = m \int^{v_2}_{v_1} \frac{dx}{dt} dv
$$

There is clearly a change of variables happening but I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Alternatively, if you have a link to a source that goes into this proof in more detail that'll probably cover it so please leave it in the comments!

Thanks.

Comment: A kind of similar question was asked on [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/572956/253530).

Comment: That was pretty useful, I'll see if I can answer my own question with the info on that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a good explanation for my specific issue with this step in the reply by user [Brick](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/89784/brick) to [this question on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/573232).

We start off with the Chain Rule,
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}= \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt}, \text{ for } y=y(x(t)).
$$

In our case, $v(x(t))=y(x(t))$. So we have

\begin{align}
\text{LHS } &= m \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{dv}{dt} dx \\
    & = m \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} dx \\
\end{align}

for clarity, I'm going to treat this as a change of variables with $u$, but you could just "cancel" the $dx$ at this point.

Let
$$
u = \frac{dx}{dt} \left( = v \right).
$$

Then,
$$
\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt}, \text{ so } du = \frac{dv}{dx} dx.
$$

Additionally, for the boundaries,
\begin{align}
\text{when } x &= x_1, ~u = \frac{dx}{dt}(x_1) = v(x_1) = v_1, \\
x &= x_2, ~u = v(x_2) = v_2.
\end{align}

Now it's easy to apply this change of variables:

\begin{align}
m \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} dx &= m \int_{v_1}^{v_2} \frac{dx}{dt} dv \\
    &= \text{ RHS}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is always good to see the formal methods behind the "magic tricks" that physicists often use